# tensorflow2.2.0 + Cuda11.0 GPU test returns False

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, cudnn

I'm working on a `windows-10` pc with a GeForce `GTX-980Ti`.

I installed the latest Nvidia Driver `451.67`, Visual Studio 2019 version `16.6.4`, `tensorflow-gpu 2.2.0`. Then I downloaded and installed `cuda 11.0` and `cuDNN8.0.1 RC2` for `cuda11.0`.

I'm able to verify the installation and run the sample programs.

The Problem arises when I try to test it in anaconda:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2020-07-20 23:29:09.430847: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
>>> tf.__version__
'2.2.0'
>>> print(tf.test.is_gpu_available())
WARNING:tensorflow:From <stdin>:1: is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.
2020-07-20 23:29:13.406332: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-07-20 23:29:13.418916: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x2706c6031b0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-07-20 23:29:13.422382: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-07-20 23:29:13.425719: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-07-20 23:29:13.456071: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:03:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 980 Ti computeCapability: 5.2
coreClock: 1.228GHz coreCount: 22 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 313.37GiB/s
2020-07-20 23:29:13.461916: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-07-20 23:29:13.467883: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_10.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_10.dll not found
2020-07-20 23:29:13.474696: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-07-20 23:29:13.479956: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-07-20 23:29:13.490763: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-07-20 23:29:13.493807: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_10.dll not found
2020-07-20 23:29:13.498571: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_7.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_7.dll not found
2020-07-20 23:29:13.501335: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1598] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2020-07-20 23:29:13.601860: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-07-20 23:29:13.606065: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0
2020-07-20 23:29:13.609379: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N
2020-07-20 23:29:13.615932: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x2707213a850 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-07-20 23:29:13.618721: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 980 Ti, Compute Capability 5.2
False
```

And:

```
    >>> tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
2020-07-21 13:18:04.066692: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-07-21 13:18:04.096830: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:03:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 980 Ti computeCapability: 5.2
coreClock: 1.228GHz coreCount: 22 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 313.37GiB/s
2020-07-21 13:18:04.101741: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-07-21 13:18:07.858480: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_10.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_10.dll not found
2020-07-21 13:18:07.937031: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-07-21 13:18:07.981968: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-07-21 13:18:08.309451: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-07-21 13:18:08.314100: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_10.dll not found
2020-07-21 13:18:08.320636: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_7.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_7.dll not found
2020-07-21 13:18:08.325392: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1598] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]
>>>
```

Can someone tell me why it is looking for outdated dll? I've read that I could manually add dlls but doing so is not advised. Does anyone have a solution to this?

I installed `python 3.8.4` from the python website but `anaconda` gives me this:

```
(base) PS C:\Windows\system32> python --version
Python 3.7.6.
```

Probably not related, just wanted to mention it. Thank you!

Comment: TensorFlow uses specific CUDA versions, in this case CUDA 10.2 and cuDNN 7, you cannot use newer version that it was compiled against, so you need to install those exact versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `Tensorflow-2.2.0` on `windows` doesn't support `CUDA-11.0` and `CuDNN-8.0`, it supports `CUDA-10.1` and `CuDNN-7.4` as given in their documentation.

[image]

[image]

I suggest you to do following things:

1. Uninstall `tensorflow-gpu`
2. Remove all versions of `CUDA` and `CuDNN`
3. Install `CUDA-10.1` and `CuDNN-7.4`
4. Install `tensorflow-gpu`

> From [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup) => In particular, TensorFlow will not load without the `cuDNN64_7.dll` file.

Note:

- Refer this to install `Tensorflow` with `pip` on windows - https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#1.-install-the-python-development-environment-on-your-system
- If you need any help with `Tensorflow` on `anaconda` environment refer this - https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/